# R- How to merge multiple dataframes of different lengths?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have been stuck with this issue for a while now. Need some help.
I am reading the following files (which can be mire than 3 files files) into a dataframe.
My input files look like the following:
file1:

```
someName    someMOD someID
A   T754(P),M691(O),S692(P),S694(P),S739(P),S740(P),S759(P),S762(P) 1
B   S495(P) 2
C   S162(P),Q159(D) 3
D   S45(P),C47(C),S48(P),S26(P) 4
E   S18(P)  5
```

file2:

```
someName    someMOD someID
C   S162(P),Q159(D) 3
D   S45(P),C47(C),S48(P),S26(P) 4
F   S182(P) 6
E   S18(P)  5
Z   Q100(P) 9
A   T754(P),M691(O),S694(P),S739(P),S740(P) 1
```

file3:

```
someName    someMOD someID
A   T754(P),M691(O),S692(P),S694(P),S739(P),S740(P),S759(P) 1
B   S495(P) 2
D   S45(P),C47(C),S48(P),S26(P) 4
E   S18(P)  5
F   S182(P) 6
L   Z182(P) 8
C   S162(P),Q159(D) 3
```

My Code:

```
  fileList <- dir(pattern="*.xls")
  i<-1
  j<-1
  a<-list()
  mybigtable<-data.frame

  for (f in 1:length(fileList)){
    fileName <- fileList[f]
    X <-read.xls(fileName)
    if(regexpr("Drug_Rep", fileName)[1]>0){
      a[[i]]<-X
     }
      i=i+1
    }
    else{
        #Don't do anything
    }
  }

  #Now i want to merge my dataframes
  mymerge <- function(x, y)
    merge(x, y, by=c("someName", "someID"), all=TRUE))

  Reduce(mymerge,a) #passing my list of dataframes 'a'
```

I did dput() on my 'a' list:

```
list(structure(list(someName = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "L"), class = "factor"), 
    someMOD = structure(c(6L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 1L), .Label = c("S162(P),Q159(D)", 
    "S18(P)", "S182(P)", "S45(P),C47(C),S48(P),S26(P)", "S495(P)", 
    "T754(P),M691(O),S692(P),S694(P),S739(P),S740(P),S759(P)", 
    "Z182(P)"), class = "factor"), someID = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 8L, 3L)), .Names = c("someName", "someMOD", "someID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L)), structure(list(someName = structure(1:5, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), someMOD = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("S162(P),Q159(D)", "S18(P)", "S45(P),C47(C),S48(P),S26(P)", 
"S495(P)", "T754(P),M691(O),S692(P),S694(P),S739(P),S740(P),S759(P),S762(P)"
), class = "factor"), someID = 1:5), .Names = c("someName", "someMOD", 
"someID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)), structure(list(
    someName = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
    "C", "D", "E", "F", "Z"), class = "factor"), someMOD = structure(c(2L, 
    5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("Q100(P)", "S162(P),Q159(D)", 
    "S18(P)", "S182(P)", "S45(P),C47(C),S48(P),S26(P)", "T754(P),M691(O),S694(P),S739(P),S740(P)"
    ), class = "factor"), someID = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 1L)), .Names = c("someName", 
"someMOD", "someID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L)))
```

What is my mistake in populating a list? Any help is really appreciated.
I am just trying to get an out put like the following:

[image]

Comment: The code I gave you before--using `Reduce` and `merge`--works perfectly on your data. Are there ONLY three datasets that you're merging, or more?

Comment: @HongOoi, I agree that in this case it seems to work perfectly, but it *looks* like they are actually probably looking for something dealing with *reshaping* data rather than *merging* data.

Comment: @HongOoi, actually, it looks like a variant of `cbind` might even be a candidate here. Perhaps `cbindX` from the "gdata" package.... But I don't think that would do any matching....

Comment: @HongOoi : there can be more than 3 dataframes. Thats why i want to dynamically create the list.

Comment: Run `lapply(a, colnames)` and inspect the result. The guess here is that your `.xls` pattern is picking up files you did not mean to. Also it would be nice to tell us what the problem is. Are you getting an error message (which one?) or if no error, why is the output not looking like you want it to.

Comment: I find it funny that instead of dealing with your problem while you were using `read.table` here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256946/r-how-to-read-multiple-text-files-into-data-tables-and-merge-on-specific-column you decided  to switch to `xls` files. Isn't Excel so much better?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is that you're actually not trying to `merge` in the standard sense, but `reshape`. In this case, you can `rbind` all the `data.frame`s together after adding a "time" variable, and use `dcast` from "reshape2" to get what you're after:

#### Add a "time" variable and `rbind` the `data.frame`s together

```
temp <- do.call(rbind, 
                lapply(seq_along(a), 
                       function(x) data.frame(a[[x]], time = x)))
head(temp)
#   someName                                                 someMOD someID time
# 1        A T754(P),M691(O),S692(P),S694(P),S739(P),S740(P),S759(P)      1    1
# 2        B                                                 S495(P)      2    1
# 3        D                             S45(P),C47(C),S48(P),S26(P)      4    1
# 4        E                                                  S18(P)      5    1
# 5        F                                                 S182(P)      6    1
# 6        L                                                 Z182(P)      8    1
```

#### Transform the `data.frame` from a "long" format to a "wide" format

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(temp, someName + someID ~ time, value.var="someMOD")
#   someName someID                                                       1
# 1        A      1 T754(P),M691(O),S692(P),S694(P),S739(P),S740(P),S759(P)
# 2        B      2                                                 S495(P)
# 3        C      3                                         S162(P),Q159(D)
# 4        D      4                             S45(P),C47(C),S48(P),S26(P)
# 5        E      5                                                  S18(P)
# 6        F      6                                                 S182(P)
# 7        L      8                                                 Z182(P)
# 8        Z      9                                                    <NA>
#                                                                 2
# 1 T754(P),M691(O),S692(P),S694(P),S739(P),S740(P),S759(P),S762(P)
# 2                                                         S495(P)
# 3                                                 S162(P),Q159(D)
# 4                                     S45(P),C47(C),S48(P),S26(P)
# 5                                                          S18(P)
# 6                                                            <NA>
# 7                                                            <NA>
# 8                                                            <NA>
#                                         3
# 1 T754(P),M691(O),S694(P),S739(P),S740(P)
# 2                                    <NA>
# 3                         S162(P),Q159(D)
# 4             S45(P),C47(C),S48(P),S26(P)
# 5                                  S18(P)
# 6                                 S182(P)
# 7                                    <NA>
# 8                                 Q100(P)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the code I gave you before is that `merge` gets confused if there are any duplicate column names, *and* you're merging more than 3 datasets. You'll have to rename your `someMOD` columns so they don't clash. A `for` loop works as well as anything for this purpose.

```
dupvars <- which(!names(a[[1]]) %in% c("someName", "someID"))
for(i in seq_along(a))
    names(a[[i]])[dupvars] <- paste0(names(a[[i]])[dupvars], i)

# and then merge
Reduce(mymerge, a)
```